# How to print barcode label using window print function?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails app. I have created barcode using barby gem and able to print it with window.print(). Now my project require these barcode in label format. I have window label printer and able to print stuff from outside of my rails app. I am clueless about label printing.

I have created a separate page in view for label printing and tried to design it from by css but it did not work and its printing in A4 size in normal printer. When I try to print with label printer it is showing no error and also not printing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to print barcode label through CSS trick. 
I have defined barcode image height, width and position in @media print and it works.